# Get a 401 error with Backbone only when I hit a page directly

Tags: api, backbone.js, routes, refresh

I have a 401 error in my local Backbone app deployment (and 500 on the live test deployment) if I hit page directly from the url bar. I don't have the problem when I request the base route and curiously either when I click on a button that will fetch the page.
The view is an array listing a collection of items.
I would like the user able to refresh the page.

I new to Backbone, so it is very difficult for me to debug efficiently.

I used `$(document).ajaxError` with `if (xhr.status == 401)` nested inside which is called. But I don't want to call the login route since the goal is just to refresh the page.

Here is some of the code:

```
var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    return this.bind("all", this.change);
  },
  routes: {
    "": "main",
    "users": "users",
    "user/:id": "user",
    "stores": "stores",
    "store/add": "addStore",
    "store/edit/:id": "editStore",
    "store/:id": "store"
  },
  dashboard: function() {
    return ROOT.VIEW = new MainView();
  },
  stores: function() {
    return ROOT.VIEW = new StoresView({
      collection: new Stores()
    });
  },
  store: function(id) {
    return ROOT.VIEW = new StoreView({
      model: new Store({
        id: id
      })
    });
  }
});


$((function(_this) {
  return function() {
    _this.USER = new Administrator();
    _this.MAIN = new MainView({
      model: _this.LOGIN = new LoginState()
    });
    $('#view').html(_this.MAIN.render().el);
    _this.App = new MainRouter();
    Backbone.history.start({
      pushState: true
    });
    return $.ajaxSetup({
      statusCode: {
        401: function() {
          localStorage.setItem('apiKey', null);
          return location.reload();
        }
      }
    });
  };
})(this));
```

Any suggestions or advice would be more than welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: share some code probably router and related views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like the login callback function was called too late in the process, that's to say right after the request which of course failed. I fixed this with a jQuery promise and also by checking the login status and the current route with Backbone.history.location.pathname. If a user is not logged in and try to connect to the page directly, I just redirect him to the root of the project, since there is just one entry point in this application.